# event after firebase is loaded into the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I want to change the color of font in an input field depending on the value coming from firebase.

In jquery I use $(document).ready() but my code fires before the firebase data is loaded into the dom.

I have reverted to using using setTimeout() to give the dom enough time to load which is not really the way to do it.

There must be an event the fires after the data is attched to the DOM?

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $firebaseObject) {

      var ref = new Firebase('xxxxxxxxx');
      $scope.Details = $firebaseObject(ref);

//what I really need is, "tell me when the firebase object is loaded to the DOM 
//so I can do my stuff"


    setTimeout(function(){ 
      if($("#idInput").val() ==='foo'){
      $("#idInput").css("color", "red");
      }
    }, 500);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$loaded()`, if you need to use the data from the `$firebaseObject`.

```
$scope.Details = $firebaseObject(ref);
$scope.Details.then(function(data) {
   // loaded data here
});
```

Otherwise though, the `$firebaseObject` informs the `$digest` loops when the data has loaded.

Another tactic is to use `resolve` in the router to load the data into the controller. This is much cleaner, because you don't need to unwrap the promise.

```
.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('home', {
    controller: 'myCtrl',
    template: 'myTemplate.html',
    resolve: {
      details: function($firebaseObject, $stateParams) {
        var ref = new Firebase('xxxxxxxxx');
        var childRef = ref.child($stateParams.id);
        return $firebaseObject(childRef).$loaded();
      }
    }
  });
})
```

Then in your controller the data will be resolved:

```
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, details) {
  $scope.Details = details; // totally available to use
})
```

[**Read the docs for more information on resolving data with routing and AngularFire.**](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html#section-routers)

Comment: I really liked that, but I am appending the $stateParams on the end of the firebase URL var ref = new Firebase('xxxxxxxx' + $scope.currentState + ''); and my app.config doesn't really like me trying to get  $scope.currentState = $stateParams.id; within the state config

Comment: You can inject $stateParams as well

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect how you can use `$stateParams` in the `resolve` object.

Answer (score 0):

Don't seems that you need to use `setTimeout` here, you could use `ng-class` directive to apply CSS on change of input value.

**HTML**

```
<input id="idInput" ng-model="idInput" ng-class="{ 'red': idInput == 'foo' }"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.red {
   color: red;
}
```

If you are really interested to do something after data gets loaded through `$firebaseObject(ref)` then you should use `$loaded` method over `$firebaseObject` which will get called once data loaded. Will prefer to use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout` to make sync scope variable binding with html by running digest cycle. Additionally don't do DOM manipulation from controller its considered as antipattern.

**Code**

```
$scope.Details = $firebaseObject(ref);
$scope.Details.$loaded()
.then(function(data) {
    //do some code
    $timeout(function(){ 
        //you shouldn't use DOM manipulation from angular controller.
        //if($("#idInput").val() ==='foo'){
        //$("#idInput").css("color", "red");
      }
    }, 500);
})
```

Comment: I tried this, the data shows in the console but the data is not attached to the dom before the alert fires  $scope.Details.$loaded()
.then(function(data) {
    //do some code
    console.log(data);
    alert(33);
});

Comment: ng-class="{ 'red': idInput == 'foo' }" this worked really well but when I tried ng-class="{ 'red': idInput == 'foo',  'red': idInput == 'bar'}" it only evaluates the last expression "bar" btw: i really appreciate your help

Comment: Thanks its obivious assignment for the latest variable will get prefrence in javascript..If you wanted to achieve the same which you are trying you could do `ng-class="{ 'red': idInput == 'foo' || 'bar'}`

Comment: @PankajParker I tried that and it throw's the argument as true whether is "foo" "bar" "a" "b" and so on... so it's throwing true all the time

Comment: @Jason sorry that was my bad..it was wrong syntax, it should be `ng-class="{ 'red': (idInput == 'foo' ||  idInput == 'bar')}`